# Autocomplete by method return type in Swift / XCode

Tags: xcode, swift, autocomplete

So in Obj-C, you could do following: You start typing, type + or - and then return type of method, and it would filter out results of autocomplete to only include methods that return that type, like this:

[image]

This is extremely helpful in some cases where your methods begin with the same prefix (ie. tableview delegate methods). But as it stands out, this is currently not possible with swift methods, or at least I have not figured out how to do it.

Is there a way using just clean XCode, or maybe some extension to it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried
http://szulctomasz.com/xcode7-native-fuzzy-autocompletion/
or
https://github.com/FuzzyAutocomplete/FuzzyAutocompletePlugin
?

Could be worth a try.

Comment: The fuzzy autocomplete plugin works, but is not extremely good for swift in my case. I have my hopes high for the native autocompletion though, did not know that! I am accepting your answer for that :) Thanks!